Error C1007: Unrecognized Flag '-archSSE2' After Upgrading Project to Visual Studio 2022
I've encountered an issue after upgrading my project to Visual Studio 2022. During the build process, I have the following error:

LINK : fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-archSSE2' in 'p2'
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed

I've edited for checking the .vcxproj file and all imported .props files, but none of them explicitly reference SSE2. I've also tried forcing the project to use /arch:AVX in both the C/C++ > Additional Options and Linker > Additional Options, but the problem persists. The flag seems to be injected somewhere, but I can't locate the source.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or does anyone know how to override or remove the -archSSE2 flag when it's not directly specified in the project files?
I've tried to force to use other instruction set but it is ignored also notice that VS uses /archXXX instead of -archXXX so I cannot imagine where the problems comes from since it compiled flawlessly in VS2019.

You left out the :.  The flag is -arch:SSE2 (but that's on by default for x86-64, so it might not even be valid for 64-bit builds.)

You are right and that's even more weird literally VS triggers
34>LINK : fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-archSSE2' in 'p2'
34>LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
without the :
Btw I'm just compiling for x64

I trust -archSSE2 is what Intel C++ Compiler accepts on other platforms, in Windows it is /arch:SSE2 and /archXXX (without colon) I've never seen. Some mysterious visual studio errors can go away if to quit it and then erase all the .vs and out and whatever other output directories that your projects produce.

what's the linker command line in the project settings?

I've already deleted the .vs folder, and the commandline is empty (I mean the editable part) the full one is too long to be pasted but has no references to SSE

Do note that this is a linker error.  The only scenario I know of where the linker starts the compiler is a PGO build, so could be caused by corrupt PGO data.  /arch:SSE2 is not terribly unusual either, it is the default for a x86 build.  So could be caused by the x86 linker starting the x64 compiler.  Without any insight in the project and no detailed msbuild trace, these are necessarily just wild guesses.

@ÖöTiib - MSVC on Windows accepts options in - form as well as / form.  https://godbolt.org/z/9G7KfnY87 shows MSVC accepting -O2 -arch:SSE2.  (And ICC-classic warning that it's "ignoring unknown option -archSSE2". ICC classic was designed to try to work as a drop-in replacement for GCC or MSVC in build scripts, so ignoring unknown options instead of erroring like MSVC or GCC makes some sense.  ICC-classic accepts MSVC-style -arch:SSE2, GCC-style -msse2, or its own native -x options like -xHOST = -march=native)
